How to subtract the means of specific columns from other preceding columns?
I would like to subtract the mean of each of the "blank" columns from each of the values on the preceding 3 columns in a dataset that looks something like this:
df <- data.frame(da=1:5, d2=6:10, dd=2:6, 
                blank...1=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1), d5=2:6, dg=7:11, 
                di=3:7, blank...2=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1), dm=21:25, 
                h4=5:9, d7=26:30, blank...3=c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1))

df
#   da d2 dd blank...1 d5 dg di blank...2 dm h4 d7 blank...3
# 1  1  6  2       0.1  2  7  3       0.2 21  5 26       0.1
# 2  2  7  3       0.1  3  8  4       0.2 22  6 27       0.3
# 3  3  8  4       0.4  4  9  5       0.4 23  7 28       0.4
# 4  4  9  5       0.2  5 10  6       0.1 24  8 29       0.4
# 5  5 10  6       0.1  6 11  7       0.1 25  9 30       0.1

In other words, I want to subtract the mean of blank...1 to each value of columns da, d2, and dd; then subtract the mean of blank...2 to each value of columns d5, dg, and di and so on. The actual dataset actually has 15 blanks that need to be subtracted from the prior 11 columns.
I have generated the means of all the "blank" columns in a vector using colMeans but then I do not know how to write the function to indicate which value to use for which columns.
How can this be accomplished through a function?

It looks like this wide data is begging to be made long, which would make the operation trivial. I would suggest building long data early in the analysis and making it wide again only for reports as late as possible if necessary

Here's another base R approach inspired by jpsmith:
blanks = grep("blank", names(df))   # find the blank columns
blank_means = colMeans(df[blanks])  # get their means

## subtract blanks means from the non-blank columns
## this relies on having exactly 3 non-blank columns per blank column
df[-blanks] = Map("-", df[-blanks], rep(blank_means, each = 3))
df
#     da   d2   dd blank...1  d5   dg  di blank...2    dm   h4    d7 blank...3
# 1 0.82 5.82 1.82       0.1 1.8  6.8 2.8       0.2 20.74 4.74 25.74       0.1
# 2 1.82 6.82 2.82       0.1 2.8  7.8 3.8       0.2 21.74 5.74 26.74       0.3
# 3 2.82 7.82 3.82       0.4 3.8  8.8 4.8       0.4 22.74 6.74 27.74       0.4
# 4 3.82 8.82 4.82       0.2 4.8  9.8 5.8       0.1 23.74 7.74 28.74       0.4
# 5 4.82 9.82 5.82       0.1 5.8 10.8 6.8       0.1 24.74 8.74 29.74       0.1


Here's a more verbose tidyverse approach. First I make the data long, tracking the original row and what group of "blank" each column should use.
library(tidyverse)
df_long <- df |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row) |>
  mutate(group = cumsum(lag(name |> str_detect("blank"), 1, 0)), .by = row)

Then I can change each value to subtract the related "blank" average (by subtracting of mean of values in the group where the name contains "blank") and reshape wide again.
df_long |>
  mutate(value = if_else(name |> str_detect("blank"), value, 
                         value - mean(value[name |> str_detect("blank")])), 
         .by = group) |>
  select(-group) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

Result
# A tibble: 5 × 13
    row    da    d2    dd blank...1    d5    dg    di blank...2    dm    h4    d7 blank...3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1  0.82  5.82  1.82       0.1   1.8   6.8   2.8       0.2  20.7  4.74  25.7       0.1
2     2  1.82  6.82  2.82       0.1   2.8   7.8   3.8       0.2  21.7  5.74  26.7       0.3
3     3  2.82  7.82  3.82       0.4   3.8   8.8   4.8       0.4  22.7  6.74  27.7       0.4
4     4  3.82  8.82  4.82       0.2   4.8   9.8   5.8       0.1  23.7  7.74  28.7       0.4
5     5  4.82  9.82  5.82       0.1   5.8  10.8   6.8       0.1  24.7  8.74  29.7       0.1


I am sure there is a more elegant solution, but in base R you can first identify those with "blank" in the name (blnknms), then use lapply to iterate through those columns and subtract the mean of that column from the three previous columns:
# get columns with "blank" in the name
blnknms <- grep("blank", names(df))

df[,-blnknms] <- unlist(lapply(blnknms, \(x){
  df[,(x-3):(x-1)] - mean(df[,x])
}), recursive = FALSE)

Output:
#     da   d2   dd blank...1  d5   dg  di blank...2    dm   h4    d7 blank...3
# 1 0.82 5.82 1.82       0.1 1.8  6.8 2.8       0.2 20.74 4.74 25.74       0.1
# 2 1.82 6.82 2.82       0.1 2.8  7.8 3.8       0.2 21.74 5.74 26.74       0.3
# 3 2.82 7.82 3.82       0.4 3.8  8.8 4.8       0.4 22.74 6.74 27.74       0.4
# 4 3.82 8.82 4.82       0.2 4.8  9.8 5.8       0.1 23.74 7.74 28.74       0.4
# 5 4.82 9.82 5.82       0.1 5.8 10.8 6.8       0.1 24.74 8.74 29.74       0.1


Thanks AC_06 - it works perfectly on my end (I just copied and pasted it from scratch), so not sure where the issue is

If you repeat each of the colMeans as many times as the respective non-"blank*" slices have columns, you can just subtract the resulting vector from the slices as a whole. Note, that to subtract a vector from columns, we need to transpose and re-transpose.
> bl <- grepl('^blank', names(df))
> df[!bl] <- t(t(df[!bl]) - rep(colMeans(df[bl]), each=which.max(bl) - 1L))
> df
    da   d2   dd blank...1  d5   dg  di blank...2    dm   h4    d7 blank...3
1 0.82 5.82 1.82       0.1 1.8  6.8 2.8       0.2 20.74 4.74 25.74       0.1
2 1.82 6.82 2.82       0.1 2.8  7.8 3.8       0.2 21.74 5.74 26.74       0.3
3 2.82 7.82 3.82       0.4 3.8  8.8 4.8       0.4 22.74 6.74 27.74       0.4
4 3.82 8.82 4.82       0.2 4.8  9.8 5.8       0.1 23.74 7.74 28.74       0.4
5 4.82 9.82 5.82       0.1 5.8 10.8 6.8       0.1 24.74 8.74 29.74       0.1

This avoids loops (incl. lapply and Map) or reshaping and is thus more efficient.
